# performance on Android 4.x

Tags: android

I am facing some performance issue (UI loading is slow) on android 4.x versions but my application is working perfectly well on android 2.x device.
Even a layout of few buttons and edit text are loading very slow
Is there any specific settings or twiking we have to made to make it work.

Please share your experience as I am struggling it with very badly.

Comment: On Emulator or device?

Answer (score 0):

you could include `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` inside the  in your manifest.
But it sounds to me you have bigger problems deeper in the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

I have already used it but no difference

there is nothing much in the .java as well as in layout file.
It is just a login page and connection to server happedn only with user clicks on login button.
this is the only code i have in my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >

    <!-- stitches for top, bottom, right, left -->

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/stitch_top_full" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/stitch_bottom_full" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/stitch_left_full" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/stitch_right_full" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/login_img_radial_bg" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/login_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/login_img_logo" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_membership_number"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/login_logo"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/textbox_layout_border"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:hint="@string/hint_cp_membership_number"
            android:maxLength="15"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true" />
        <!-- android:background="@drawable/login_textbox_bg" -->

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_membership_password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/login_membership_number"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/textbox_layout_border"
            android:hint="@string/hint_cp_membership_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLength="15"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/login_row"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/login_membership_password"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/login_stayloggedin_bg"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.60"
                android:background="@drawable/login_img_remeber_bg"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <!-- android:background="@drawable/login_stay_loggedin_bg" -->

                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/login_stay_login_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/login_stay_loggin_btn_drawable"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:textOff=""
                    android:textOn="" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/stay_login_label"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.40"
                android:background="@drawable/login_img_button_bg" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/login_bttn"
                    style="@style/textView_style"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/login_button"
                    android:text="@string/btn_title_login" />


            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- </RelativeLayout> -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/login_copyright"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/login_row"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:typeface="normal" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_slider_open"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/login_img_slider_open"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <TextView
            style="@style/textView_style"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:text="@string/not_a_member_label" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/common_img_largebuttonbg1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/login_signup_bttn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/login_img_btn_signup"
                android:text="@string/btn_title_sign_up"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_slider_close"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/login_img_slider_closed" >

        <TextView
            style="@style/textView_style"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:text="@string/not_a_member_label" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: start with a 9patch instead of 4 imageviews.

Comment: then, a button alone in a relativelayout doesn't make much sense

Comment: hi these 4 images are stitches I have used at top, bottom, left and right side. secondly why I have used relative layout with button is because as per design there is some image on the top of it i have put button

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the problem, our issue is resolved now.
I would like to share my experience so that it might help others too.

What we were doing:
we were using **text shadow for text in the textview** and this was creating issue in android 4.x device, but working perfectly in android 2.x devices.

what we did:
we just remove the shadow elements from the textview and now it is working perfectly fine.

so this is our findings on android 4.x version.